# sqldf R - days between orders - group by client

Tags: r, date, sqldf

I want to obtain the average time between orders grouping by Client. I want to do this with sqldf library R.

Test data:

```
  > test
+    CLIENT ORDERS_DATE
+    1   2014-09-22
+    1   2014-12-16
+    2   2014-10-08
+    2   2014-10-12
+    2   2014-10-26
+    2   2014-11-06
```

sqldf code:

```
> avg.time.orders.before = sqldf("SELECT CLIENT , AVG(ORDERS_DATE - lag_orderdate) AS avg_time_between_orders
FROM (
SELECT CLIENT , ORDERS_DATE , LAG(ORDERS_DATE) OVER (PARTITION by CLIENT ORDER BY ORDERS_DATE) AS lag_orderdate
 FROM  test
)
GROUP BY CLIENT")
```

I obtain the following error message: "Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: near "(": syntax error"

Comment: `LAG(ORDERS_DATE) OVER (PARTITION by CLIENT ORDER BY ORDERS_DATE)` is a SQL Server feature; `sqldf` is (likely) using SQLite as its SQL engine, so that will not work.

Comment: The default for sqldf is SQLite but other drivers can be used if desired. See the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lag`, `partition by`, `over`, etc. can only be used with the PostgreSQL backend to sqldf.  Assuming you are using the default SQLite backend and assuming that we want the average difference for the orders sorted in ascending order we can do this.

Suppose there were 4 orders at times t1 <= t2 <= t3 <= t4. Then the average difference would be

```
((t4-t3) + (t3-t2) + (t2-t1)) / (4 - 1)
= (t4 - t1) / (4 - 1)
```

where t1 is the oldest order and t4 is the newest.  Thus, in general the telescoping sum reduces to the difference between the last and first order and the average is that divided by the number of orders minus 1.   Thus we have:

```
sqldf("select CLIENT, (max(ORDERS_DATE) - min(ORDERS_DATE)) / (count(*) - 1) AVG_DIFF 
       from test 
       group by CLIENT")
```

giving:

```
  CLIENT  AVG_DIFF
1      1 85.000000
2      2  9.666667
```

We can double check this by checking that it gives the same answer as the following -- this will give the same answer if the orders are sorted within CLIENT which seems to be the case in the question:

```
aggregate(ORDERS_DATE ~ CLIENT, test, function(x) mean(diff(x)))
```

**Note:** We assume this input:

```
test <-
structure(list(CLIENT = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), ORDERS_DATE =     
structure(c(16335, 16420, 16351, 16355, 16369, 16380), class = "Date")),   
.Names = c("CLIENT", "ORDERS_DATE"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```